# doc.fromHTML is not a function jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Hello Im trying to save my html page to PDF and I have this code:

```
 <div id="content">
<h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

<p>a pararaph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>

<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {   
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});

// This code is collected but useful, click below to jsfiddle link.
</script>
```

I uploaded to jsFiddle and works... but when I try it in my browser doesnt works and I get the error doc.fromHTML is not a function. I have the jQuery and jsPDF references exactly like jsFiddle.

[Example Code](https://jsfiddle.net/dpqgccL9/)

Comment: Please check jspdf.min.js is available in your local html

Comment: Yes, is available. The error comes when I click on cmd.

Comment: Can you check whether both the Jquery and jspdf files are available 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>

Comment: Because i tried to replicate and it works fine in my local and codepen -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKKNMK

Comment: Maybe its for my jQuery version? Im using 1.12.3

Comment: Oh yes..Can you try replacing with the script tag which i have provided ..hope it works :)

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: Was the jsPFD file, thanks!

Comment: Yes bro, post it as answer to vote for you.

Comment: Thanks Flores :) done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add External libraries - Jquery and Jspdf js files with script tags

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKKNMK

Answer (score 25):

The `fromHTML` function was replaced by `html` in 2.0.0. Unfortunately, the typings currently still contain the fromHTML method but a fix is under way.

Comment: Adding a complement/reference to the comment above:

- http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html

Comment: @Alexa, But i am also getting  error Uncaught TypeError: doc.html is not a function

Comment: @NarenVerma revisa si has importando las librerías necesarias